# Send Email Only When Disk Drive is Below Threshold

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I have researched Google and tried several different options and none of them provide the result that I'm looking for. This script produces the email with the data I'm looking for but it sends the email regardless of the threshold. I would appreciate assistance with knowing what I need to change so that the script will only send the email when the drive is below threshold.

```
$freeSpaceThreshold = 5GB
#$computerName = "mycomputer"
$drive = "C:"

$driveData = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}

if ($driveData.FreeSpace -lt $freeSpaceThreshold)
    {
        $from = "user@domain.com" 
        $to = "admin.user@domain.com" 
        $subject = "Low Disk Space!" 
        $body = "Free Space Remaining: " + "$($CDisk.FreeSpace)GB" + " Drive" + $_.deviceid 
        $smtpServer = "smtp.domain.com" 
        $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
        $smtp.Send($from,$to,$subject,$body) 
    }
```

Comment: Does the value for `$freeSpaceThreshold` need to be in double-quotes?

Comment: @spikey_richie I changed it to single quotes and it still send an email even though threshold is only set to 5GB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got a working script. This is the answer I was looking for. Hope it helps others.

```
$minGbThreshold = 29;
$computers = $env:COMPUTERNAME;
$smtpAddress = "smtp.yourdomain.com";
$toAddress = "anyemail@gmail.com";
$fromAddress = "anyotheremail@gmail.com";
foreach($computer in $computers)
{    
    $disks = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DriveType = 3";
    $computer = $computer.toupper();
    $deviceID = $disk.DeviceID;
    foreach($disk in $disks)
    {
        $freeSpaceGB = [Math]::Round([float]$disk.FreeSpace / 1073741824, 2);
        if($freeSpaceGB -lt $minGbThreshold)
        {
            $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpAddress)
            $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
            $msg.To.Add($toAddress)
            $msg.From = $fromAddress
            $msg.Subject = “Diskspace below threshold ” + $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId
            $msg.Body = $computer + "\" + $disk.DeviceId + " " + $freeSpaceGB + "GB Remaining";
            $smtp.Send($msg)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`5GB` resolves to `5368709120` which is the same value but in bytes instead of gigabytes.

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> $freeSpaceThreshold = 5GB

PS C:\Windows\system32> $freeSpaceThreshold
5368709120
```

When you use it in a comparison, you need to divide it the same way you divide the comparison value. e.g `($_.FreeSpace / 1GB)` and `($freeSpaceThreshold / 1GB )`. or you simply don't divide at all because the freespace property is also bytes.

Also, do your calculation stuff before the formatting. I'd do it like this:

```
$freeSpaceThreshold = 5GB
$Computer = "MyComputer"

# The Disks Variable will contain all Disks that are below the freeSpaceTreshold
$Disks = Get-CimInstance Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer | 
            Where-Object { $_.DriveType -eq 3 -and $_.FreeSpace -lt $freeSpaceThreshold }

if ($Disks) {
   # Put your Formatting and E-Mail Code here.
}
```

Then you'll get the correct result.

Comment: The result I want is the script not to send an email if disk space is above the threshold. The answer you provided doesn't do that.

Comment: @Manning yes it does exactly that. you use this: `@{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}`. But use `$freeSpaceThreshold = 5GB`and then you compare those two `$driveData.FreeSpace -lt $freeSpaceThreshold`. Read the answer again and try to figure it out. You basically do the formatting before the comparison. That's why you get the email always, not just if the disk space is below the treshold. The answer I provided will simply return the desired disks into the `$Disks` variable. you can take it from there and do your formatting.

Comment: @Manning This is by the way the exact same answer that you already got when you asked this question on SO a few months ago. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59056797/powershell-script-send-email-only-when-drive-space-is-below-minthreshold

Comment: I didn't accept the answer at that time either because it didn't help me resolve the problem of the email being sent regardless of the disk space on the drive. It only explained the math and how it worked to get GB rather than bytes.

Comment: @Manning yeah but that's exactly the problem why the email gets sent, because your math is wrong! let's say your free space is 8GB. that's 8589934592. but you always divide it by 1GB. that's 8. and then you compare the int 8 to 5GB which is the int 5368709120. 8 is lower than 5368709120. that's why you always get an email. just don't divide by 1GB!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [why are you not using the built-in PowerShell mail cmdlet](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-7) vs using the .Net mail namespace?

Secondly, you are using variables in the body that are not declared and $PSItem (aka $_.) is not being passed at all in the code post you've made.

```
# Your declared variable
$freeSpaceThreshold = 5GB
#$computerName = "mycomputer"
$drive = "C:"

# Variables you are trying to use that don't exist from the above
"$($CDisk.FreeSpace)GB" + " Drive" + $_.deviceid
```

Lastly, you are getting everything because that is specifically what you are asking for.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $Computer -Filter DriveType=3 | Select-Object DeviceID, @{'Name'='Size (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.size / 1GB)}}, @{'Name'='Freespace (GB)'; 'Expression'={[math]::truncate($_.freespace / 1GB)}}
```

Point Of Note: Avoid the use of property names, filenames, that have spaces if you control that. You'll just have unnecessary headaches with a bunch of quoting stuff.

So, try it this way. 
*(The formatting is just my readability habit. So, use what you like.)*

***Updated based on your comment on auth and SSL below***

```
$freeSpaceThreshold = 500
$computerName       = $env:COMPUTERNAME
$drive              = 'C:'

$driveData = Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName $computerName -Filter DriveType=3 | 
Select-Object DeviceID, 
@{
    'Name'       = 'Size'
    'Expression' = {[math]::truncate($PSItem.size / 1GB)}
}, 
@{
    'Name'       = 'Freespace'
    'Expression' = {[math]::truncate($PSItem.freespace / 1GB)}
} | Where-Object -Property Size -lt $freeSpaceThreshold 

<#
# Results

DeviceID Size Freespace
-------- ---- ---------
C:        476       120
D:        476       357
#>


if ($driveData.FreeSpace -lt $freeSpaceThreshold)
{
    $SendMailMessageSplat = @{
        From       = "$env:USERNAME@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"  
        To         = "$env:USERNAME@$env:USERDNSDOMAIN" 
        Subject    = "Warning hostname $computerName Low Disk Physical Space" 
        Body       = "Free Space Remaining: $($driveData.FreeSpace)GB  Drive  $($driveData.deviceid)" 
        SmtpServer = "smtp.$env:USERDNSDOMAIN"
        UseSsl     = $true
        Port       = 587 
        Credential = Get-Credential
    }

    Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageSplat
}
```

Comment: postanote, I get the following error. Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
At line:34 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageSplat

Comment: Take a look at the cmdlet help file to see how to add the ssl and auth properties and add those to the hash table of the splat. [Send-MailMessage (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage)